# Mailchimp Custom Automation Suggestions?

Tags: mailchimp

Not sure if this is even possible - but we are looking for a way to trigger mailchimp newsletters based on a custom field value in a Wordpress website.

Basically we will have a field value that holds "the number of miles" a person has walked based on the data they enter. We will be calculating the "total miles".....when they reach 100 miles for example we will need an email to trigger from Mailchimp....then 200 miles will trigger a 2nd email and so on....

Does anyone know if this can even be done with Mailchimp? If not is there a better approach to handling this?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Do you have any PHP for things that you have tried?

Comment: And yes, it can be done with the API - but you have to write something for it to check their status and then add them to the queue. PLUS - your end users will of course have to agree to be added to a MC list. Which you can also do with the API :)

Comment: Thanks Scoopzilla -- we have not tried anything yet. We are getting a quote together for the group, we just have not done anything similar to this to be able to gauge difficulty. We wanted to make sure it could be done! Mailchimp experts we are not!  :-) We may have to bring someone in for this piece of the puzzle!

Comment: Might I suggest - me? :D

Comment: LOL -- if we get the job we will absolutely reach out for this piece for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Python, I'd recommend using a Jupyter notebook for this to cut down on development work. You could set it to run at regular intervals checking the status of each user (running either on your computer or a server), then updating the merge tag of the status in mailchimp. You can have automations that are triggered when the merge tag of distance is a specific value, say 100 they get the 100 email, 200 they get the 200 email. (You could also do it so when a user hits a certain milestone their merge tag is updated in MailChimp but from my experience that's a little more work.)

Net net there are a few ways to achieve your goal but I think using a Python notebook using pandas to manipulate the data and the [mailchimp3 mailchimp API](https://github.com/charlesthk/python-mailchimp) client would be the lightest lift.

TIP: Mailchimp currently has a bug where merge tags information is not always accurately represented in the UI. So for example if via the API you added 500 people with the Distance merge value of 200, and checked that via the UI how many people had a value of 200 for Distance you would likely see an inaccurate number displayed for the count in the UI. If you export the list, you will see the correct number that is reflected in your API update. To be clear, in some cases UI does not display the accurate number for users with that merge tag or value, but if you export the list with that merge tag/value via the UI it should match what you pushed to the API. This is currently an open ticket.